# Extension of a charge from an algebra to a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be an algebra of subsets of a set $\Omega$. Let $\lambda$ be a finitely additive probability measure (i.e. a charge) on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$. Suppose $A_i\in \mathcal{F}$ and $\lambda(A_i)=1$, $i=1,2,\ldots$. Let $\sigma(\mathcal{F})$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{F}$. It is well-known that there exists an extension of $\lambda$ from $\mathcal{F}$ to $\sigma(\mathcal{F})$. The question is, does there exist an extension $\bar{\lambda}$ of $\lambda$ such that $\bar{\lambda}(\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i)=1$ or $\bar{\lambda}(\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i)>0$?